# how to display order grand total in Magento API extension?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to extend Magento API. By now i have been able to do some things but I'm stucked with somthing that should be really simple. I can't get the order Grand Total. I just get an empty array when I try to do so. Please help!

```
<?php
class Neurona_Pagoexpress_Model_Sales_Order_Api_V2 extends Neurona_Pagoexpress_Model_Sales_Order_Api
{
    public function pago($ref, $medio, $moneda, $boleta)
    {
    $order = $this->_initOrder($ref);
    return $order->getGrandTotal();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($order->getData())` and show it to us?

Comment: var_dump($order->getData())  =   NULL

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to this

I used a Magento API method:

```
$orderInfo = $this->info($ref);
$total = $orderInfo[grand_total];
```